# Pass variable/intent to an activity when launched from a Widget

Tags: android, android-activity, android-widget

Currently within an activity in my application I can call another activity and pass a variable to it in the following manner:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(parentView.getContext(), ShowStations.class);
myIntent.putExtra("stationName", stations[position].StationName);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

This works fine, but now I want to be able to do the same from my Widget.  Currently this code works fine for launching a specific activity from my widget:

```
Intent WidgetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER).setComponent(new ComponentName("grell.com", "grell.com.FavStations"));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, WidgetIntent, 0);
    updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_main, pendingIntent);
```

So now I am wondering how can I launch the same activity as shown in the first example but also pass through the 'stationName' variable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent widgetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER).setComponent(new ComponentName("grell.com", "grell.com.FavStations"));  
widgetIntent.putExtra("stationName", stations[position].StationName);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, widgetIntent, 0);    
updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_main, pendingIntent);
```

Check if above code works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck.  It would seem that maybe it has to be done somehow with the pending intent??